# Get actual index during insertion in a BST

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I want to create a BST, which on insertion of element will return the index of it in a perfectly balanced tree. For example (the number in parenthesis indicates actual index) :

```
  5(1)
    / \
   /   \
  3(2)  6(3)
 /
2(4)
```

or

```
1(1)
 \
  \
   2(3)
    \
     \
      3(7)
```

In the second example, we can see that there is no left child of element 1, but still element 2 has an index of 3, as that would be the case in a perfectly balanced tree.

The root node starts with 1.

What would be an efficient way to return the index on insertion?

Now in insertion of an element in a BST my code is as follows:

```
Node newNode = new Node(id);
if(root==null){
            root = newNode;
            return 1;
        }

Node current = root;
        Node parent = null;
        while(true){
            parent = current;
            if(id<current.data){                
                current = current.left;
                if(current==null){
                    parent.left = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }else{

                current = current.right;
                if(current==null){
                    parent.right = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

I am not able to understand how I should maintain which level the element is being inserted in to calculate the index.

The number of elements which can be inserted is at max 3*10^5. Storing in an array to get the indexes wont be an effective method

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to represent the binary tree as a one-dimensional array. This is common in implementations of binary heaps.

Your implementation would not be balanced like a heap must be, but you can use the same concepts, since you can know that there is 2^i spaces at each level i (starting with 0 for the root) in a binary tree.

Your implementation would need to change from Nodes with left and right pointers, to a one dimensional array of the whatever data type the tree holds (integer in your case).

You can navigate the tree by calculating indices:

- parent of node i: array[i/2]
- left child of node i: array[2i]
- right child of node i: array[2i+1]

info obtained from http://www.cse.hut.fi/en/research/SVG/TRAKLA2/tutorials/heap_tutorial/taulukkona.html

Comment: I definitely thought about using arrays, however I failed to mention that number of elements will be at max 3*10^5. Using array indexes will not be a good solution.

Comment: @user1692342 I don't see how that would any adverse affect on this implementation

Comment: It matters. If the input is in increasing order. Then, the elements will be inserted in 1, 3,7, 15, and so on. Very quickly the array index will grow extremely huge and I wont be able to store the array at all.

Comment: @user1692342 I thought you meant the node value, not index. I understand now. Good luck in that case.